# Create a urdf/xacro file from model of FreeCAD

Tags: ros, rviz, urdf, ros-melodic, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone.

I have created the following model in FreeCAD of a robot with differencial cinematic system (back wheels do the traction):

[image: Model in FreeCAD]

I would like to create the urdf/xacro files to see it navigating in Rviz from this model, but I don't know if it is possible or I have to write theese files by myself.

I am using ROS melodic version.

Any help I would be very grateful.

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355109/create-a-urdf/xacro-file-from-model-of-freecad/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I post a new autoanswer because finally I found a solution.

1. In FreeCAD export the model as Collada (.dae).
2. Copy the file into your package, in a folder called "meshes".
3. Create an urdf file with the following content:

`

`

(I don´t know why the format of the code is wrong)

4. Launch the urdf file with robot_state_publisher package as normal.

With this I can use my model of FreeCAD to see it in rviz, without create a complex urdf file.

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

Originally posted by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) with karma: 113 on 2020-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-06-19**:
This gets you a static mesh. It visualises in RViz yes, but that's not what people typically want when they ask how to convert `<insert CAD program here>` to URDF.

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-06-22**:
Yes, I know is a static mesh, but for my application is enough because my robot just have the wheels as mobile part, so I just want to visualize the robot. Thank you for the information by the way.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm unaware of any solutions using FreeCAD specifically, but you can check out [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create%20a%20URDF%20for%20an%20Industrial%20Robot) which links to [this package](http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter). A similar approach could be made with FreeCAD.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2020-06-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2020-06-18**:
Thank you very much for your answer. I will try and if it works I mark the answer as correct.

Best regards.